# Django 1.0 Testing: how do I get a session to persist between test code and view being tested?

Tags: python, django, testing

I am trying to test how a view behaves when there is certain data stored in the session. To do so I have created the session in the test method and invoked an interactive shell at the very beginning of the view:

**Test Method:**

```
def test_user_with_unused_tests(self):
    "User is given a test and sent to test start"
    # todo: insure that the user is given a test that he hasn't done

    #login
    login = self.client.login(username='xxx', password='xxx')
    self.failUnless(login)

    # build the screener
    user = User(username='xxx', password='xxx')
    user_screener = UserScreener(user=user)

    # put the screener in session
    self.client.session['user_screener'] = user_screener
```

**View That Is Tested:**

```
@login_required
def screener_start(request):

    import code
    code.interact(local=locals())
```

But apparently the session does not persist between my test method and the call to the view:

**Evidence of Nonpersistence:**

```
>>> request.session.values()
[1, 'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend']
```

Is there any way to fix this? Am I missing something essential?

I am using Django 1.0.

Thanks ahead of time for your thoughts.

Comment: There are a couple relevant bugs with work-arounds for this issue: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/15740 and https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/10899

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need a `setUp` method, please lookup http://docs.python.org/library/unittest.html for `setUp` and `tearDown` method documentation. The setUp will be run for all tests, the code for each individual test will be destroyed at the end of each test run.

Essentially, you need to put your login logic in the `setUp` and the actual test logic in the test method.

Hope this helps